# How is the HAVING clause optimized in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

In PostgreSQL, if we have such a query:

```
SELECT --
FROM --
WHERE -- 
GROUP BY --
HAVING
   func1 AND func2;
```

I think there could be three strategy in planner:

1. func1 first perform on target list then func2 on same target list
2. func1 first perform on target list, generate a smaller result set, and then func2 perform on the small result set
3. suppose func1 cost c1, func2 cost c2, and c1>c2, func2 first perform on target list ,  generate a smaller result set, and then func1 perform on the small result set

   which one is the actually approach in PostgreSQL?

Comment: The best reference for this is the source code. PostgreSQL has a cost-based planner, so look into the cost estimates logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If either `func` is a non-aggregate and non-[`VOLATILE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/xfunc-volatility.html) expression, the planner may effectively move it to the `WHERE` clause.

Otherwise, `(func1 AND func2)` would be applied as a single filter expression on the resulting groups. At this point, the executor's [lazy boolean evaluation rules](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-EXPRESS-EVAL) kick in; if the first condition evaluates to `false`, it will not bother to execute the second. So the behaviour is closest to your second or third options, but performed in a single pass of the result set.

The order of evaluation is up to the planner, so in theory it may decide to execute `func2` first. However, I'm not sure what might trigger this behaviour; even when `func1` has a cost of 1000000000, it still seems to favour left-to-right evaluation.

The `EXPLAIN ANALYSE` output will show you where in the execution plan that these conditions are applied, and by adding some `RAISE NOTICE` statements to the body of the functions, you can observe the exact sequence of function calls.

Comment: Just to be clear, since the grouping and filtering happen in separate stages of execution, it cannot lazily evaluate the aggregate functions themselves. So in something like `... HAVING SUM(x) > 10 AND COUNT(*) > 1`, it will always count the records; the only unknown is whether it will bother comparing that count to 1.